# How to output "stopped" events in Visual Studio Code debugger

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I am writing my own debugger in VS code for a custom language. Everything works fine, when I click "step over" my program is being debugged correctly, but I cannot see anything in the editor. I think the problem is the "stoppedOnStep" event, I followed the tutorial here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/debugger-extension but there is no way to send line number or file name in the "stopped" events.

Here is the event in the code example: `this.sendEvent(new StoppedEvent('step', MockDebugSession.THREAD_ID));` and as you can see, no info on file name of line number, so I have no idea how that part of the debugger works. How does the debugger client know on which line is the program stopped? Is there some secret `getLine()` method that reads the line number from the runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer is in the stack trace. After the `stopOnStep` event (or any other event), the editor sends a stack trace request to the debugger, and the last entry is the current line of the execution.

Comment: I know it's been a while since you've stumbled upon this issue but I'm currently in the same place. My case is that I'm writing a custom debugger that's based on WebSockets and I need to stop in certain place based on a WebSocket event. Any ideas on how I could achieve that?

Comment: @AbsoluteZero I was modifying an interpreted language, so I just added the communication with the debugger to the interpreter, if you have a similar use case, just fond the code that interprets the place you want to debug, and add the check for the event there.